Is there a way to use Espanso to unlock xflock?
I locked my PC session using xflock however wasn't able to unlock it using Espanso.
I tried to use the text-expander Espanso to unlock my locked xflock-session with it, however the text-expander gets deactivated once xflock gets activated - as I have no in-depth knowledge about both I wanted to ask if there is any possible workaround or configuration/possibility to not automatically disable Espanso during the lock. This might sound dull but I wanted to also understand why it works using Plasma but not with XFCE.
